# wordpress.com website url structure

Tags: urls, htaccess, wordpress.com-hosting

Should I able to change URL structure of WordPress blog? (Free WordPress hosted blog)

Right now I have this way: (see URL structure)

```
helloworld.wordpress.com/london
```

But I want to use as this way:

```
helloworld.wordpress.com/carhire/uk/london
```

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is achievable and quite simple to do so. Go to **Settings** > **Permalinks** in your admin area.

There you should be able to select **Custom** and use a value like (if you want all URLs to start with /carhire/uk/)

```
/carhire/uk/%postname%/
```

If your logic is more complex, I suggest using a plugin such as [Custom Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/).

**Edit:**

I just tried it myself, on the wordpress.com free plan it seems that you can't change permalinks at all (neither via settings nor via plugin). If you upgrade to the Business plan (~24$/mo), it is possible to install plugins - and the aforementioned should solve this.

Comment: I can't see any section for "permalinks" in my settings. I'm using wordpress hosted blog.

Comment: @MarkNsu Yeah, sorry, you can't. Either change the plan, or to wordpress.org or another hoster

Comment: It's ok brother :)

Comment: that got nothing to do with being a free plan, you just can't change pemalink in a multisite "blog"

Comment: @MarkKaplun Can't you change them via plugin even in multisite? Plugins are only available for business plans

Comment: do not remember the details off hand, but in practice you are unlikely to be able to set permalink that do not match the permalink that the network owner support, and the nature of such sites is that the people using "blogs" are not technical enough to even understand the implications of changing those settings. As for the "business" plan, it seems like it runs in some kind of VPS setting, or at least as independent install, and then you might have control, but it depends on what exactly wordpress.com gives there (which is why the question is off-topic in the first place)

Answer (score 2):

If you use wordpress.com, you can't change the permalinks. You have to use the original wordpress.org version and host it on your favourite webhoster.